# Bit wise or of two Unsigned Integer (Program Crashes)

Tags: c, crash, bitwise-or

Sorry if my problem is not very clear.
I've a structure like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t typeSet;
}DataTypeTagInfo;
```

The following function is for unifying two typeSet:

```
DataTypeTagInfo* unifyTagInfo(DataTypeTagInfo* tag1, DataTypeTagInfo* tag2){
    if(tag1 == NULL) return tag2;
    else if(tag2 == NULL) return tag1;
    tag1->typeSet |= tag2->typeSet;
    return tag1;
}
```

The program exits while executing the following line:

```
    tag1->typeSet |= tag2->typeSet;
```

On a sample run I've following value:

```
tag1->typeSet = 3917954189
tag2->typeSet = 2536589
```

There is no error message. Just quits. Please help.

Comment: Care to give us an error message or some other clue? And you might need to post more code.

Comment: [Can you show the full test code?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: tag1 is a structure just having a field typeset, which is unsigned int. The program just exits without showing anything.

Comment: What do you expect your program to show?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? Tried to step through the code? Checked that the pointers look valid (i.e. not `NULL` and not some value like `0xcdcdcdcd`)?

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is perfectly sound.  Consequently, it's very likely that either `tag1` or `tag2` is an invalid pointer at the time of the abort.  This will have nothing to do with the code you've posted. The pointers could be set invalid in many, many ways.

To figure out what's happening, I'd start with a careful review of the code setting `tag1` and `tag2` at the call site and then - if the answer does not appear - move on to using `valgrind` to check for memory overwrite errors.

NB this what makes C(++) so challenging.

Comment: Yes, Illegal structure pointer was the problem. Thanks.